# Magento2.4: How to display coupon code in Sales order Grid and Sales order detail page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I want to display coupon codes in the sales order grid and the order detail page.
Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps.

1. Add below code in di.xml

```
    
        
            sales_order.coupon_code
```

2. Create new column in sales order grid table by db_schema.sql file
3. Create sales_order_grid.xml at app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component

Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column


text
true
text
left
Coupon Code

4. For one time updates Run below query

   update sales_order_grid set coupon_code=(select coupon_code from sales_order where sales_order.entity_id=sales_order_grid.entity_id)

Answer (score -1):

Try below code here is the sales order grid show coupon code.

1. Override the Order Grid: In the module, you need to override the Order Grid by creating a new column to display the coupon code. To do this, create a new file in the path **`Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`** and add the below code.

Here is the code.

```
<column name="coupon_code" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CouponCode">
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
         <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Coupon Code</item>
      </item>
   </argument>
</column>
```

2. Create a Column File: Now, create a new file in the path **`Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/CouponCode.php`** and add the below code.

Here is the code.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTimeFormatterInterface;

class CouponCode extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
   protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
   protected $dateTimeFormatter;

   public function __construct(
      ContextInterface $context,
      UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
      CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
      DateTimeFormatterInterface $dateTimeFormatter,
      array $components = [],
      array $data = []
   ) {
      $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
      $this->dateTimeFormatter = $dateTimeFormatter;
      parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
   }

   public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
   {
      if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
         $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
         foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
            $order = $this->_getOrder($item["entity_id"]);
            if($order->getCouponCode()) {
               $item[$fieldName] = $order->getCouponCode();
            }
            else {
               $item[$fieldName] = '-';
            }
         }
      }
      return $dataSource;
   }

   private function _getOrder($id)
   {
      $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('*');
      $collection->getSelect()->where('entity_id=?',$id);
      return $collection->getFirstItem();
   }
}
```

And try below code for sales order detail.

In the module, create a new file in the following path:
**`app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>/view/adminhtml/templates/sales/order/view/info.phtml`**

```
<?php
    $couponCode = $block->getOrder()->getCouponCode();
    if ($couponCode) {
        echo __('Coupon Code: %1', $couponCode);
    }
?>
```

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: This solution provided a bad performance.

Comment: Can you provide best performance solution?

Comment: You should add the coupon_code to the table sales_order_grid by adding that column to the sales order grid insert sales_grid_order_async_insert